# How to load assets in Camaleon Cms Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, camaleon

I have installed a custom theme in Camaleon Cms and put the images in the following folder:

```
app/apps/themes/<theme name>/assets/images/
```

When I try to load the image by using the following path:

```
<%= image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "logo", :width => "", :height => "") %>
```

then it looks for the image inside main asstes folder of the project i.e.:

```
app/assets/images/
```

but I want to look it inside the assets folder of the theme I installed.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

add image load path in the tag to load image from your selected theme folder

```
<%= image_tag theme_asset_path("images/logo.png"), :title=> "logo" %>
```